# Spring JPA save transient entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

in hibernate if I `persist` new entity it should become managed , moreover it should return the managed entity.

if the entity is detached , the `merge` will return managed entity but the one that I passed will still detached.

I've tried that in spring boot with hibernate and everything is working except the following case :

```
User transientUser=new User();
    transientUser.setId(9L);
    User managedTransientUser=userRepository.save(transientUser);
```

if I set the Id manually ( even with removing the auto generation) the entity that I pass ( transientUser) will still be unmanaged . If I use generation Identity then the returned and passed entity are the same ( the id is null and the DB will auto increment ) is that expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because you're not calling `persist()`. You're calling `userRepository.save()`.

This method tests if the entity is new (by checking if it already has an ID). If it is, it calls `persist()`. Otherwise it calls `merge()`. Since your entity already has an ID, it calls `merge()`.

Comment: so do you mean that it checks the ID only ? it doesn't check if it has value in the database ?

Comment: No, Spring-data-jpa doesn't. JPA does when calling merge(), though.You should avoid using non-generated IDs in general. If you do use non-generated IDs, then I would explicitly call persist() when you want to persist() instead of using save().